# Using regex capture group from blackbox exporter in prometheus.yml

Tags: prometheus

Blackbox exporter lets me match a regex after connecting to an http port.  I'd like to use a capture group in the regex in other places.  For example, I'd like to connect to the http port of a web server with blackbox, and extract the current number of connections to that server from the returned data, and pass that back to Prometheus to display to the user.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not possible with the blackbox exporter, which is (largely) just for pass/fail.

What you are looking to do is write an exporter, https://www.robustperception.io/writing-a-jenkins-exporter-in-python/ has one example.